# Issues with sharing repository between linux and windows

Tags: linux, windows, git

I am sharing my repository between my linux and windows machine and pushed some permission changes on my linux machine.

Now my windows machine says I'm up-to-date when doing this:

```
git fetch -all
git reset --hard origin/master
git pull
```

yet when I attempt to do the following:

```
git checkout dev
```

It suddenly tells me I have local changes, which just so happen to be the same files of which I modified the permissions on my linux machine.

What is the right way of dealing with this? I made those permission changes so I don't have to manually use `chmod` every time I pull on my linux machine.

Comment: I suspect that you might have a line endings problem here.  Windows and Linux use different line endings, and that you touched those files in Linux might mean that the endings were somehow changed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I configured my windows git installation to always use linux line endings for both pull and commit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `core.fileMode` to `false` on Windows, then the executable bit is ignored for the windows repo.

Comment: Thanks! that worked! (interestingly enough only when I did it using `git config core.fileMode false` without the `--global` argument)

Comment: That is probably, because `clone` tries to determine whether your filesystem supports the executable bit and sets the property on your repository automatically. But it might be wrong or change, e. g. if you clone with Cygwin Git but then use Git for Windows, or clone on ext3 and then access the repo by a CIFS share. Thus the property was likely set on repository level, so global level was overwritten.